# How to combine information in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is an example of a dataset I need to work with (CSV with delimiter ;)

```
2018-01-01 00:06:06;read;country_2;2458151267;Reddit;Europe
2018-01-01 00:06:15;read;country_6;2458151268;AdWords;Europe
2018-01-01 00:07:21;read;country_7;2458151269;AdWords;North America
2018-01-01 00:07:29;read;country_5;2458151270;Reddit;North America
2018-01-01 00:07:41;subscribe;2458151268
2018-01-01 00:07:44;subscribe;2458151267
```

I can see in line 2 that the customer with ID = 2458151268.0 read my product and then subscribed to it (line 5). Since line 5 doesn't bring a lot of info, how can I see where my subscribers are coming from (country, source and continent)? How do I properly read this CSV file in pandas?

I have 7000 subscribers to work with so if you have an idea or can point me to the right direction thank you so very much!

I've tried a bunch of groupby() that did not work out!

When I use

```
data = pd.read_csv('example.csv', delimiter = ';')
```

my dataset doesn't come correctly since the "subscribe" line doesn't have all info that the "read" line does!

Comment: Your dataset seems to have the `ID` in the `Country` column in the second row

Comment: @Nick The csv file my data came from doesn't have the correct space after the delimiter for all the subscribe lines. What do you recommend here?

Comment: Maybe you need to filter your csv file and read the `read` lines into one df and the `subscribe` lines into another, and then merge them. You really need to add a more complete example of your dataset (as *text*, not an image) to your question to make it possible to offer good suggestions to solve the problem.

Comment: @Nick I copied part of my CSV file here so you have an idea and maybe give me some tips. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this is to first clean up the data by copying the `country` value from the `subscribe` rows into `ID`, then merging non-read events with the corresponding read event and filling `NaN` values from that. For example:

```
# Sample data from question
text = '''2018-01-01 00:06:06;read;country_2;2458151267;Reddit;Europe
2018-01-01 00:06:15;read;country_6;2458151268;AdWords;Europe
2018-01-01 00:07:21;read;country_7;2458151269;AdWords;North America
2018-01-01 00:07:29;read;country_5;2458151270;Reddit;North America
2018-01-01 00:07:41;subscribe;2458151268
2018-01-01 00:07:44;subscribe;2458151267'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep=';', header=None, names=['TIME', 'Event', 'Country', 'ID', 'Source', 'Continent'])

# rows with no id
noid = df['ID'].isna()

# copy country value into `ID`
df['ID'] = df['ID'].fillna(df['Country']).astype('int64')

# set the corresponding country values to `NaN`
df.loc[noid, 'Country'] = np.nan
```

Output at this stage:

```
                  TIME      Event    Country          ID   Source      Continent
0  2018-01-01 00:06:06       read  country_2  2458151267   Reddit         Europe
1  2018-01-01 00:06:15       read  country_6  2458151268  AdWords         Europe
2  2018-01-01 00:07:21       read  country_7  2458151269  AdWords  North America
3  2018-01-01 00:07:29       read  country_5  2458151270   Reddit  North America
4  2018-01-01 00:07:41  subscribe        NaN  2458151268      NaN            NaN
5  2018-01-01 00:07:44  subscribe        NaN  2458151267      NaN            NaN
```

Now we merge events with no data with those that have one and fill `NaN` values from them:

```
gotdata = df['Country'].notna()
out = df[~gotdata].merge(df[gotdata], on='ID', suffixes=['','_y'])
out = (out
    .fillna({'Country' : out['Country_y'], 'Source' : out['Source_y'], 'Continent' : out['Continent_y'] })
    .drop(columns=[f'{col}_y' for col in df.columns if col != 'ID'])
)
```

At this point, we have

```
                  TIME      Event    Country          ID   Source Continent
0  2018-01-01 00:07:41  subscribe  country_6  2458151268  AdWords    Europe
1  2018-01-01 00:07:44  subscribe  country_2  2458151267   Reddit    Europe
```

Now we add this back to the rows which have data:

```
out = pd.concat([df[gotdata], out]).sort_values('TIME').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
                  TIME      Event    Country          ID   Source      Continent
0  2018-01-01 00:06:06       read  country_2  2458151267   Reddit         Europe
1  2018-01-01 00:06:15       read  country_6  2458151268  AdWords         Europe
2  2018-01-01 00:07:21       read  country_7  2458151269  AdWords  North America
3  2018-01-01 00:07:29       read  country_5  2458151270   Reddit  North America
4  2018-01-01 00:07:41  subscribe  country_6  2458151268  AdWords         Europe
5  2018-01-01 00:07:44  subscribe  country_2  2458151267   Reddit         Europe
```